# Yii2 ActiveForm dropDownList value set in the form but empty in beforeSave

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've been looking for this everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

I am using Gii CRUD generator which I customized for fields to update. Nothing to do with validation rules because I don't get any error.

**Here is the scenario:** I want a dropDownList from which the user selects a list item and the item is updated in the model.

**Problem:** When I log the values in _form.php, they are correctly retrieved and displayed on the form. However, when I click the update button and log the model values in beforeSave, I find that target field is empty. I get no errors and the model is saved with an empty field.

Below is my code.

**_form.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    ....

    <?php $list = ArrayHelper::map($this->context->getListItems($model->id), 'id', 'item'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'item')->dropDownList($list, ['prompt'=>'Select...']) ?>

    ....

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

    ....

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit();

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }

    ....

?>
```

The result of the above:

```
frontend\models\Model Object
(
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            ....
            [id] => 14
            [item] => 
            [last_modified] => 2016-09-28 13:16:43
            ....
```

Notice how **item** is empty.

Any hint?

Comment: Is form displays selected item on update?

Comment: You say it has nothing to do with validation rules but if you use `load()` method on model, and there are no rules for attribute defined, this attribute is not set, so maybe this is why `item` is empty.

Comment: @InsaneSkull yes it displays correctly. However, @Bizley is right. It had to do with `load()` hence with validation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell the real problem but in my case I had 2 models, the child with its own rules and the parent with its own rules. I tried to merge the two rules (from parent and child models) and it didn't work. So I moved all rules in the parent model.